# Cloud page with html only

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

We are building a cloud page with a form using **html/javascript only** so not Smartcapture.

If I had a form field in the cloud page as mandatory or "required" with the value being passed to a DE field which is **Nullable** attribute would that be ok?

I know this is a problem when we use SmartCapture so i thought of building using html only.

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is no such constraint.
Your form built via "standard" html can be built as you wish. Standard html forms only do frontend validation, which means there simply is no connection to the data extension field constraints (which is backend validation). Data coming in from your form is treated like data from any other basic source, say entered manually.

And from there it's logic. A "nullable" field CAN be null. Which means it doesn't HAVE to be null, so sending data into this field every time is totally fine.

Comment: Thank you Jonas